# Dynamic updates on a pair of charts when zoomed

Tags: javascript, highcharts

([JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/A9xjh/1/))

I have a pair of time-series charts with a common logical x-axis that are updated with series.addPoint().  Using the afterSetExtremes() event, I have set things up so that zooming in on a region on one chart will also zoom in on the same region of the second chart, like so:

```
    xAxis: {
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
            if (chart2) {
                // if 'Reset Zoom' has been clicked, we need to call chart.zoomOut()
                // instead of setExtremes, otherwise new points added to the series 
                // dynamically are not shown.
                if (e.min <= e.dataMin && e.max >= e.dataMax) {
                    var ex = xaxis2.getExtremes();
                    if (ex.min > e.dataMin || ex.max < ex.dataMax) {
                        chart2.zoomOut();
                    }
                // call setExtremes if necessary (note: condition also prevents
                // infinite loop between the afterSetExtremes methods of both charts)
                } else if (xaxis2.min != e.min && xaxis2.max != e.max) {
                    xaxis2.setExtremes(e.min, e.max);
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

This works fine, however when I zoom in on some region of either chart which includes the extreme right-hand side of the chart (so that the most recently added points are visible), new points dynamically added to the series are only shown on the chart which was originally zoomed in on, while the other chart just stays fixed zoomed in on the original zoom region (i.e., the new points are not shown).

What do I need to do to get the second chart to show the dynamic updates, just as the first chart is doing?

Comment: When new point arrives, update extremes on both charts?

Comment: But if the chart is zoomed in on an area that does NOT include the RHS edge, the arrival of a new point should not suddenly cause the region to expand to include the RHS edge.  The thing is, the chart which was originally zoomed in has all the correct behaviour, the objective is to get the same behaviour from the other chart.  Notice how I had to call chart.zoomOut instead of axis.setExtremes to get the correct zoom out behaviour? It's almost like there should be an equivalent chart.zoomIn() method which is equivalent to having zoomed in on the chart manually...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setExtremes`

http://jsfiddle.net/A9xjh/4/

or

http://jsfiddle.net/A9xjh/5/

Obviously you can adapt to your specification.